# Convert numbers to rational numbers with the same denominator

Tags: syntax

Is it possible to modify an answer so that all numbers have the same denominator? E.g.

```
Table[(27 - k)/15, {k, 0, 29}]
```

returns

```
{9/5, 26/15, 5/3, 8/5, 23/15, 22/15, 7/5, 4/3, 19/15, ...
```

Would it be possible to get

```
{27/15, 26/15, 25/15, 24/15, 23/15, 22/15, 21/15, 20/15, 19/15, ...
```

The example above is trivial, but assuming an output of

```
{2/3, 3/11, 5/17}
```

one would transform it into

```
{374/561, 153/561, 165/561}
```

TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
With[{x = LCM @@ Denominator @ #}, # x / Defer[x]] & @ {2/3, 3/11, 5/17}
```

> ```
> {374/561, 153/561, 165/561}
> ```

```
Table[(27 - k)/15, {k, 0, 29}]
```

[image]

```
With[{x = LCM @@ Denominator@#}, # x / Defer[x]] & @ %
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there some method for a general "answer", like "{2/3, 3/11, 5/17}" above?

Comment: @mf67, please see the  updated version.